# Refresh div using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to refresh a select (by id) when the ajax call is successful.
But i have no idea how to process

**ajax function :**

```
$('#insertForm').on('click', function(){
  var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "lib/function.php?insertForm="+insertForm+"&form_intitule="+form_intitule,
    dataType : "html",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
    },
    success:function(data){
      /*here i need to reload #listeFormation*/      }
  });
});
```

**html.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nomSalarie" class="col-sm-1 control-label" id="nameSelect">Formations</label>
  <div class="col-sm-11">
    <select name="listeFormation[]" id="listeFormation" class="form-control" multiple>';
      while($ligne = $displayFormation->fetch()){
        $data['formation'] .='<option value="'. $ligne['form_id'].'">'.$ligne['form_intitule']. " [" . $ligne['form_organisme'] . "]".'</option>';
      }
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace your comment with `$("#listeFormation").html(data);`

Comment: my select become empty ..

Comment: Tell me what you get if you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Depends on what insert form returns exactly

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data

Comment: @LucasFrugier It is just the parameter of the function.

Comment: what ? i don't understand .. :(

Comment: are you sure server is returning the proper html?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in my thought:

1. Use the $.load() from jQuery like: (it's a GET which inject the response into the node you select)

```js
$('#insertForm').on('click', function(){
  var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val();
  
  $("#listeFormation").load( 
    "lib/function.php", 
    { 
      insertForm: insertForm,
      form_intitule: form_intitule
    },
    function(response, status, xhr){
      if(status == "error"){
        alert(xhr + '--' + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }else{
        // Process the HTML you want here.. lets call: 'html_you_want_to_inject'
        
        $('#listeFormation').html(html_you_want_to_inject);  
      }
    }
  });
});
```

2. Using your code, you could use simplely:

```js
$("#listeFormation").html(html_you_want_to_inject);
```

I guess one point to think is about to remove the PHP from the div and turn this div dinamic since the page load with your Javascript. You kill your PHP each time the AJAX runs, rewriting the content in runtime.

Comment: note this will create a POST not GET request when passing object to `load()`. Also defeats purpose of using `load()` if you manipulate response yourself

Comment: the html that i wan to inject is the same dynamic list. but when i write my code in the .html() it does not work